# How to make a join in a GORM criteria with a domain class without association ?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I use a GORM criteria to retrieve a list of Spring Security users with filtering and sorting on the properties of the user, and I would like to sort on the spring security role affected to each user. Normally, I could simply do something like this :

```
User.createCriteria() {
    [...]
    userRoles {
        role {
            order("code", "asc")
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't do this here since Spring Security doesn't define associations between User and UserRole and between userRole and Role. I've tried to find a way to make a join with UserRole despite the absence of association with User, with no success. I could also define hasMany associations in User and Role, but maybe Spring Security doesn't do this for a good reason. What would be the better solution in this case ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no reason why you shouldn't add these mappings yourself

Comment: I eventually did it this way, however I had to remove the composite key definition in UserRole because it prevents the join between UserRole and Role. I hope it won't have any bad consequences (it didn't so far).

Answer (score 0):

May be its late by now.

In case you are using the Spring Security plugin (which I assume), you will find that the plugin has generated a class **SecUserSecRole** that links SecUser to SecRole.  [Reference](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/)

This allows Many-to-Many relationship between the users and roles.

In your case, I think it is better idea to create criteria on `SecUserSecRole` instead of `User`